# Where to find C source code on mac?

Tags: c, macos, header-files

I was looking through a programming textbook and saw a particular header i didn't recognize. Later I looked it up on the internet but I was wondering where the source code of C can be found on a macbook. Is it just in the compiler? (I use gcc) Please help.

Comment: What's the name of said header?

Comment: ctype.h, but i figured out what it is, i just want to know where to find the whole source code.

Comment: ctype.h is part of the C standard library, so it *should* be present in some form if a C compiler is present. (but this is not *necessarily* the version used to compile your system, though in this case the difference may be futile)

Comment: Do you want to know where to find the *header*, or the *source code*? (I.e., do you know the difference?) `ctype.h` might be an exception, but for most standard headers your compiler does not need source code at all.

Comment: @RadLexus I'd really be interested in having the difference explained between a *header file* and *source code*

Comment: @tofro: header files usually have names that end with `.h`. Source file names can end with `.c`, `.cpp`, `.pas`, `.asm`, and oodles more. That is a handy way to tell them apart. (They also have different *purposes*, which ought be explained in a good C course.)

Comment: @RadLexus actually i do, there actually isn't that much difference look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482948/any-fundamental-difference-between-source-and-header-files-in-c

Comment: @RadLexus So, what does a header file *contain* if it isn't source code?

Comment: @tofro: ah, another easy one. Everything that is not source code, but is still needed by a compiler to compile some other source code. You may want to sign up for a C course for the details.

Comment: There actually is **no difference at all**. You can even name your header files `.c` and your compilation units `.h`if you absolutely want and the compiler will still work. It's just a *convention*. In my `ctype.h` is just about as much *source code* than in any other `.c`file on my system.

Comment: looks like tofro did his homework =)

Comment: A C compiler doesn't even *see* a header file - After preprocessing, it's just a big blob of *source code*, all the same. So there must have been source code in the headers as well ;) . I was just asking silly questions, sorry to mislead you.

Comment: There's no such thing as "the source code of C".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Apple development tools installed, it should be found in the most possible unixoid place: `/usr/include/ctype.h` - At least that's where it is on my Macbook with Xcode installed.

Answer (score 1):

The source code to much of the OS/X operating system and utilities, including the C library can be found at http://opensource.apple.com/ .

The source for the current version of the C library is here: http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1082.50.1/ .

For other packages installed via `brew` or `macports`, use the corresponding command to retrieve the source for the packages.  Look at the man page to see how.

Note that the `gcc` command actually runs `clang` on recent versions of XCode under OS/X. Try `gcc --version`...

Comment: Oh ok, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The newest (clang-based) versions of XCode seem *not* to use `/usr/include`.  I eventually found the headers down in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include`.  (I created a symlink in `/usr`, for sanity's sake.)