# Why not explicitly #include .c files?

Tags: c, compilation, linker

In the C programs I've seen .h files are always explicitly included using:

```
#include "some_header_file.h"
```

On the other hand .c files are very rarely included using:

```
#include "some_c_file.c"
```

Three questions:

1. Why the difference?
2. When would you divert from the norm and include a .c file explicitly?
3. How does the linker know that a required .c file is included in the project and where to look for it?

Comment: I think in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482948/any-fundamental-difference-between-source-and-header-files-in-c) Post some of your questions are well answered.

Comment: 1) see the post from marblixon reply; 2) rarely. Usually related to use of macro definitions. 3) linker does not care. it links `object` files which you tell it to link. It does not understand source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > Why the difference?

   To stick to a modular design approach.
2. > When would you divert from the norm and include a .c file explicitly?

   Mostly never.
3. > How does the linker know that a required .c file is included in the project and where to look for it?

   The linker does not need .c files, but .o files (for example) created by a compiler (in this question's context) from .c files. Where those .o files are located the linker is  told by its caller (IDE, makefile, user).

Comment: E en more. Linker does not care about the language. You can link object files which was written in the different languages.

Comment: @P__J__: I do not say the linker cared about the language. But I will make my answer a bit less suggestive.

Answer (score 3):

Header files specify an *interface* (function declarations, macro definitions, type definitions, etc.) while .c files specify the *implementation* (function and object definitions).

You almost never include a .c file within another .c file, primarily because it quickly becomes a maintenance nightmare if two .c files use the same symbols for different purposes, or if you have chained includes (`a.c` includes `b.c` which includes `c.c`, etc.) and you wind up with a translation unit that’s too large for a compiler to handle.  It also means that if you change an included .c file, you have to recompile everything that includes it, whether that code changed or not, which make builds take longer than they should.

**EDIT**

A third reason is that you may want to hide some data items or functions from the larger program (essentially making those items "private" to a particular source file).  If you include that source file within another source file, you lose that ability.  Again, this is a real problem if you use the same variable or function name for different purposes in different files.

**END EDIT**

Separate compilation and linking is a Good Thing, especially on large projects.

Linkers typically don’t know anything about source files - in a typical tool chain, the programmer specifies where everything is located via a makefile or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reasons for not explicitly including .c in other .c files is the desire to avoid duplicate symbols.

Consider file `a.c` that defines a global symbol (a variable or a function) names `A`. Assume `b.c` and `c.c` #include the file `a.c`. If you have a Makefile that compiles and links `b.c` and `c.c` and to build an application, you are going to have a linker failure due to duplicate definitions of `A`:

```
 A     A
 |     |
a.c   a.c
 |     |
b.c   c.c
   \  /
executable
```

In this dependency graph the executable cannot be built, unless `A` is a file-scope symbol.

The way to avoid this would be to `#include` all `.c` files in a single "master" file, which is a very restrictive design antipattern.

Comment: "In this dependency graph the executable cannot be built"
And with including .h files there won't be a problem because the scope is always local ?

Comment: If you follow the convention that symbols are just declared in .h files, not defined, *then* it will not be a problem. This is of course yet another convention that C does not enforce in any way, and there are exceptions (such as inline functions) that are fine to define in header files.