# I get undefined reference to `merge', even though I told my makefile everything I can think of

Tags: c, gcc, gnu

the error I get is: in generation.o: undefined reference to `merge'

this is my makefile:

```
game: game.c general.h generation.o
    gcc -g game.c generation.o -lm -ansi -pedantic -Wall -o game

generation.o: generation.c assembly.h general.h general.c
    gcc -c generation.c -lm -ansi -pedantic -Wall

general.o: general.h general.c
    gcc -c general.c -lm -ansi -pedantic -Wall
```

I have a function merge in general.c. it is prototyped in general.h, and generation.c has "=`#include "general.h"`
so I don't understand, what could make generation.o not know this function, it's decleared in the header that included in generation.c and all of the things are in the makefile, what am I missing?

more than a fix, I want to know why it happens, so it'll never happen again

Comment: I suspect you don't link `general.o` into `game` in the second line. You only link `generation.o` there. Your `merge` function is defined in `general.c`, isn't it?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482948/any-fundamental-difference-between-source-and-header-files-in-c

Comment: This Makefile is quite strange and inconsistent: .c files depending on other .c files, mixing compiling and linking in the build of `game`, including libraries when no linking is to be done.